# Node Module not being referenced on server

Tags: node.js, mandrill

I am trying to link the Mandrill library into my node project.

I have backtracked it right upto the following code which "stops" the project. This code is from the mandril API documentation.

```
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('My KEY');
```

I have installed the mandril api using `npm install mandrill-api` and I can see it my node_modules folder. However when I deploy the project to the server the application stops running. It clearly is not referencing properly but I don't see how.

The code is being called in config.js. I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake.

[image]

Comment: How are you passing in your key?  Is it through an environment variable?

Comment: The project still fails with the key line commented out. Its due to the `require` that the project is failing.

Comment: The issue is when you start the node server locally or after you push it to a remote server?  And how are you requiring in the `config.js` to your `app.js`

Comment: Is when I push to the server that the issue occurs

Comment: Are you have to deploy this application to server, as you said, right? Could be related to permisson?

Comment: Hi @LuizPauloCamargo. Sorry I don't understand you question?

Comment: You said, "i upload the project to the server", right? Where is this server?

Comment: Digital Ocean. Why would this matter?

Comment: can you share a log of the output from the server ?

Comment: If your server path - where your application is stored - dont have right permissions, this can be a problem. As @avrono writed, can you share a log of the output from the server?

Comment: Other Modules work fine though?

Comment: There does not seem to be a standard for the way modules work, usually the module will be in ./node_modules/module_name/lib check where the code is and maybe try use an absolute path instead of relative